# A problem with unitary matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $U$ be an $n \times n$ unitary matrix.

And let $|\cdot |^2: \mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb R_+^n$ be the function such that $|\mathbb w|^2$ is the vector which has its $i$-th entry equal to $|w_i|^2$, where $w_i$ is the $i$-th entry of $\mathbb w$.

When is there a function $f : \mathbb R_+^n \rightarrow \mathbb R_+^n$ such that for each unit vector $\mathbb z \in \mathbb C^n$, $f(\mathbb |\mathbb z|^2) = |U\mathbb z|^2$?

***Note:*** I am asking this question, because it is related to quantum mechanics; if there exists a linear function $f$ such that the above is true, then quantum mechanics could be interpreted classically. But this cannot be so, since $|U\mathbb z|^2$ is not linear. But what if $f$ is nonlinear?

Comment: I suggest using another notations for $|\cdot|^2$, because it is confusing (can be easily mistaken for absolute value of the vector). For your problem, I'd try to prove that $U$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Are there any other matrices besides diagonal matrices? That's really my question.

Comment: I'd start by playing with canonical basis of $\Bbb C^n$ to get the coefficients of $U$ and then pull a contradiction by taking some well-chosen $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, your conjecture is false. For instance, take $U=Rot(\theta),z=[\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha)]^T,y=[\cos(\alpha),-\sin(\alpha)]^T$. Then $|z|^2=|y|^2$ and $|Uz|^2=[\cos^2(\theta+\alpha),\sin^2(\theta+\alpha)^T$ and $|Uy|^2=[\cos^2(\theta-\alpha),\sin^2(\theta-\alpha)]^T$.

Keep your bounty for further opportunity.